Is it Halal to work at PayPay Corporation as a Senior Software Developer?
Assalamu Alaikum,
I have been offered a position as a Senior Software Developer at PayPay Corporation, and I am seeking guidance on whether it is permissible (Halal) to work there. PayPay is a Japanese company that develops electronic payment services. The company offers QR code and bar code-based payment services, enabling users to make payments using their mobile devices.
JazakAllah Khair for your guidance.
https://about.paypay.ne.jp/en/

Alhamdulillah,
working as a senior software developer at PayPay Corporation, which develops electronic payment services, is generally permissible (halal) in Islam with certain conditions and considerations.
there are several principles that are relevant to this situation:

Permissibility of financial transactions: Islamic law permits and encourages lawful financial transactions, business activities, and technological advancements that facilitate legitimate economic activities and provide benefits to people.
Avoidance of interest (riba): Islam prohibits dealing with interest (riba) in financial transactions. As long as PayPay's services do not involve interest-based lending or borrowing, it should be permissible to work there.
Avoidance of prohibited activities: The company's activities should not involve anything explicitly prohibited in Islam, such as gambling, alcohol, pork, or other unlawful goods and services.
Contractual obligations: The employment contract should not require you to engage in or facilitate any unlawful activities, and your job responsibilities should be compliant with Islamic principles.
Intention and benefit: Your intention should be to earn a lawful living and contribute to the development of a useful service that facilitates legitimate financial transactions and benefits society.

As long as PayPay's electronic payment services are not used for unlawful purposes, do not involve interest-based transactions, and your job responsibilities do not conflict with Islamic principles, working there as a software developer should be permissible.
However, it is always advisable to thoroughly review the company's activities, policies, and your specific job responsibilities to ensure they do not violate Islamic principles. If you have any doubts or concerns, it is recommended to consult with a qualified Islamic scholar or authority for further guidance.
And Allah knows best!

any suggestion on the qualified islamic scholar or authority?
